# Neo4j transaction misunderstanding

Tags: node.js, neo4j, neo4j-node

While I was looking over the [documentation for transactions](http://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/) I came accross on this example:

```
var tx = session.beginTransaction();
tx.run("MERGE (bob:Person {name : {nameParam} }) RETURN bob.name AS name", {nameParam: 'Bob'})
  .subscribe({
    onNext: function (record) {
      console.log(record.get('name'));
    },
    onCompleted: function () {
      session.close();
    },
    onError: function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });

//decide if the transaction should be committed or rolled back
var success = false;

if (success) {
  tx.commit()
    .subscribe({
      onCompleted: function () {
        // this transaction is now committed 
      },
      onError: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
} else {
  //transaction is rolled black and nothing is created in the database
  console.log('rolled back');
  tx.rollback();
}
```

But on snippet above it does not seem to change the `success` somehow I mean how it does determine whetherthe transaction sucessfully executed or not the `success` variable does not change the value at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are calling `session.close()` on the `onCompleted` callback function.

When you close a session, it will automatically commit all the underlying opened transactions.

Moreover on your example, you are not waiting that the `tx.run` promise is finished or not. you should do it on the section `decide if the transaction should be committed or rolled back`

So you should do something like that :

```
    var driver = neo4j.v1.driver("bolt://localhost",  neo4j.v1.auth.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"), { encrypted:false });
    var session = driver.session();
    // run statement in a transaction
    var tx = session.beginTransaction();
    tx.run("MERGE (bob:Person {name : {nameParam} }) RETURN bob.name AS name", {nameParam: 'Bob'})
      .subscribe({
        onNext: function (record) {
          console.log(record.get('name'));
        },
        onCompleted: function () {
          console.log('statement completed')
        },
        onError: function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });

    //decide if the transaction should be committed or rolled back
    var success = true;

    if (success) {
      tx.commit()
        .subscribe({
          onCompleted: function () {
            // this transaction is now committed 
          },
          onError: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
    } else {
      //transaction is rolled black and nothing is created in the database
      console.log('rolled back');
      tx.rollback();
    }
    session.close();
```

PS: I will contact the dev team to update the example

Comment: So the `var success = true;` will be updated on a custom piece of code I need to develop, that decides whether the transaction will be completed or not right?

Comment: Furthermore on the snippet seems that is no clear that the ` session.close()` gets called on any callback at all. Is is getting called outside of any promice at the code snippet.

Comment: For your first question : yes you can do what you want ! For the second quesion, the `session.close()` is just called on `onCompleted` callback, not on the other.

Comment: So the piece of code that start from `var success = true;` and end into `  session.close();` right?